# Adding reCaptcha to action.php

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

Very much an amateur developer who can cut and paste,
I am trying to add a reCaptcha v2 to an old html / php website,

I have got the captcha working, only problem is when the form is submitted it goes to the actual address /action.php and displays some code + the 'Thank you' message.

```
         <?php
if($_POST) {

require('constant.php'); 

$user_name      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_email     = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$user_phone     = filter_var($_POST["phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$content   = filter_var($_POST["content"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(empty($user_name)) {
    $empty[] = "<b>Name</b>";       
}
if(empty($user_email)) {
    $empty[] = "<b>Email</b>";
}
if(empty($user_phone)) {
    $empty[] = "<b>Phone Number</b>";
}   
if(empty($content)) {
    $empty[] = "<b>Comments</b>";
}

if(!empty($empty)) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => implode(", ",$empty) . ' Required!'));
    die($output);
}

if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>'.$user_email.'</b> is an invalid Email, please correct it.'));
    die($output);
}

//reCAPTCHA validation
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

    require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');        

    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

      if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>Captcha</b> Please try the captcha again!'));
            die($output);               
      } 
}

$toEmail = "email@email.com";
$mailHeaders = "From: " . $user_name . "<" . $user_email . ">\r\n";
    $mailBody = "User Name: " . $user_name . "\n";
$mailBody .= "User Email: " . $user_email . "\n";
$mailBody .= "Phone: " . $user_phone . "\n";
$mailBody .= "Content: " . $content . "\n";
if (mail($toEmail, "Contact Mail", $mailBody, $mailHeaders)) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .', thank you for the comments. We will get back to you shortly.'));
    die($output);
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Unable to send email, please contact'.SENDER_EMAIL));
    die($output);
}
}?>
```

The HTML is as follows

```
    <form id="frmContact" action="action.php" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="label">Name:</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
        placeholder="enter your name here"
        title="Please enter your name" class="required"
        aria-required="true" required>
</div>
<div class="label">Email:</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"
        placeholder="enter your email address here"
        title="Please enter your email address"
        class="required email" aria-required="true" required>
</div>
<div class="label">Phone Number:</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"
        placeholder="enter your phone number here"
        title="Please enter your phone number"
        class="required phone" aria-required="true" required>
</div>
<div class="label">Comments:</div>
<div class="field">
    <textarea id="comment-content" name="content"
        placeholder="enter your comments here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="**My-Site-Key**"></div>
<div id="mail-status"></div>
<button type="Submit" id="send-message" style="clear: both;">Send
    Message</button>
```

It displays the following 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOeKL.png)

I was hoping to make it not load a new webpage but to just display the message below or something.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated,
Pete

Comment: If you dont want to relod your page, use AJAX (javascript that calls your php page, waits for the result and then do something - shows some message, ...)

Comment: Does Captcha widget appear on your page? When form is submitted does it have captcha value (`g-recaptcha-response`)? At first glance I see you only check captcha if it was submitted (and you should always check it or fail if not submitted)

Answer (score -1):

I just realized that the issue is that you are using another page to process the recaptcha. If you add the HTML to the end of the php page instead, you can use the same page for both the HTML formulas, and the PhP processing. (in the old part below i thought that it was the same page) So that would solve it. Because the action.php is not the same as the formula page, it posts the output on the empty action.php page instead of the formular page. You could still do it with the javascript i listed below, IF! the PhP and HTML is on the same page that is.

Hope it helps

OLD PART BELOW!!

The reason that it outputs it like "{type:message" and stuff, is caused by the use of "json_encode". If that is not the issue, I guess that you want to just add it to the page instead. To do that, you could experiment with an AJAX request, as it can dynamically update the webpage without reloading. But what I would do (since I am a noob xD) I would make the PhP output a javascript code that changes and empty tag. like this.

```
<p id="output"></p>
```

And then add the php to output JavaScript.

```
echo '<script>var elementOfIntrest = document.getElementById("output");elementOfIntrest.innerHTML = "Hi' . $user_name . ', thank you for the comments. We will get back to you shortly.";</script>';
```

This however, will still make the webpage reload with the new information on it.

I'm not a 100% sure that it will work as you want it (not exactly sure what you want) But hope it helps.

If you want to do it with an AJAX request, you can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).